# Runtime Permissions Android

Tags: android, android-permission

Estou com alguma dificuldade em conseguir fazer o pedido das permissões em runtime, sendo que apenas o dialog de aceitação de permissões de uma das duas permissoes necessárias é mostrado quando clico no button.

```
 /*Button PANIC Button
    @ Click this button to send a PANIC message to defined contact
    @ Inside the message go a PANIC message, name of person and GPS location
    */
    Button button_panic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_panic);
    button_panic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                requestLocationPermission();
                requestSMSPermission();

                String Message = "GRANTED";
                Log.i("Location permission", Message);


            }
            else
            {
                sendMsg();
            }

        }

    });
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void getLocation() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.


        //requestLocationPermission();

        return;
    }
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    String longitudeString = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    String latitudeString = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());

    message = "PANIC - Preciso de Ajuda " + Nome + " " + Apelido + ". " + "Esta é a minha localização: Latitude: " + latitudeString + " Longitude: " + longitudeString;

    Log.e("Log Message", message);

}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void sendMsg() {

    getLocation();

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestSMSPermission();
    }

    if (location != null) {
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(Telefone, null, message, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sent to " + Telefone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(Telefone, null, "test", null, null);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please open your location service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void requestSMSPermission() {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SEND_SMS_CODE);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void requestLocationPermission() {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION_CODE);
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_COARSE_LOCATION_CODE);
}
```

A questão das permissões ao executar o metodo onClickButton é apresentada de imediato o dialog para permitir a localização, mas apos permitir a app crasha e pelos logs reporta o seguinte erro referente à falta da permissão para SMS. No entanto se eu arrancar de novo a app, agora já com a permissão para a localização garantida, e executar de novo o metodo onClickButon é apresentada o dialog para a permissão do SMS.

> java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10229 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
>                                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendTextForSubscriber(ISms.java:768)
>                                                                                       at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessageInternal(SmsManager.java:333)
>                                                                                       at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:299)

Além disso pelos log's eu consigo ver que a mensagem é gerada com sucesso, e pela impressão do Toast 'Sent to 93xxxxxxx' consigo perceber que foi executado o método mas na realidade a SMS nunca chega ao destino.

Alguém me pode ajudar a ajeitar isto de forma a conseguir ter tudo funcional...

Comment: No manifest está tudo certo né? Está dando permissão normalmente?!

Comment: Sim no manifest está certo... É algo relacionado com estas permissões em runtime requeridas pelo sdk 23 ou superior... Não sei o como corrigir essa situação e não sei o porque depois a SMS nao chegar ao destino apesar de tudo parecer correr bem com o envio

Comment: Você tentou adicionar o ActivityCompat desta forma:  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(new S...)

Answer (score 3):

Um problema que vejo é como o teste das permissões está a ser feito:

```
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

Ao usar `&&` para ligar as duas condições basta que uma delas seja falsa para entrar no `else`.

O que deve estar a acontecer é que a aplicação já tem a permissão `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, talvez concedida numa primeira execução do programa, o que faz que aquela condição seja falsa e a linha `sendMsg();` seja executada.

Lembre também que o processo de pedir uma permissão é assíncrono e o seu sucesso só é conhecido após o método `onRequestPermissionsResult()` ser chamado.

Quando necessita de pedir mais de uma permissão na mesma altura, talvez a forma mais fácil de as gerir é pedi-las em apenas uma chamada a `requestPermissions()`:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                               Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                                               Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                                  REQUEST_ALL_PERMISSION);
```

<sub>**Nota:** Não posso garantir que este seja o único problema do seu código já que não tenho uma visão geral dele.</sub>

<sub>**Observação:** Não faz sentido que as permissões sejam pedidas quando o **botão de pânico** seja clicado. Elas já deverão ter sido concedidas antes do usuário estar perante uma situação de pânico.</sub>